# How to get Learning phase status of adsets using Facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

I'm building a dashboard where I want to summarise important details about my active Facebook campaigns. I was able to connect to my Facebook ad account and retrieve my campaigns, ad sets and ads info.
I'm using PHP SDK for Facebook Marketing API.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/v3.2

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any way to get information about the Learning Phase Progress regarding my campaigns.

Is there any way to get / calculate this status?

https://www.facebook.com/business/help/112167992830700

Comment: I'm in a similar position. Given that their official documentation https://www.facebook.com/business/help/112167992830700?id=561906377587030 is saying it is a feature they are gradually introducing, chances are it's not fully deployed and that work is still on-going, including on the API in relation to this. That's all assumption though.